# LESS escaping not working

Tags: css, gulp, escaping, less, calc

I'm using Gulp (w/ Gulp-LESS) to compile LESS to CSS. For some reason, it's not recognizing when I try to escape a CSS calculation.

Both of these:

```
height: ~"calc(100vh - 50px)";
height: calc(~"100vh - 50px");
```

Always compiles to this:

```
height: calc(50vh);
```

I know there's a way to turn on Strict Math in LESS, but I'm not sure how to do that within the Gulp workflow.

Comment: This kind of stuff usually appears if you accidentally compile your files twice... So make sure you do not compile your resulting CSS files with Less too.

Comment: That's fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and there was a twice compiling issue. I had not any access to solving the compiling issue, So just did a little trick, by twice escaping the string. This will work for cases that have twice compiling issue:

```
height: ~'~"calc(100vh - 50px)"';
```

Answer (score 0):

As @seven-phases-max said, the issue is I was accidentally compiling it twice. Fixing that made the escaping work. Thanks!